# Through board connector

Tags: connector, through-hole

I'm looking for a connector. Ideally it would be a one pin connector mounted on the back side of a board and the pin would come through the board into connector.

Here's an illustration:

[image]

Does such a thing exist? And if so what's its name and where can I buy one (or actually about a hundred).

Comment: What's the required pin diameter and length?

Comment: Yes, they exist (although I can't immediately recall what they are called or who makes them).  I think, even onesies like that exist.  What pin diameter?  How much current?

Comment: Pins are about 0.3-0.5mm. Current is under 500mA.

Comment: through board connector something like [this?](https://wwws.samtec.com/technical-specifications/default.aspx?seriesMaster=BCS)

Comment: @user44635 Almost. That one assumes mounting on the face side of the board and that pin goes through connector and then trough the board. I would like one that's mounted on the back side of the board. But if there's none, this may be an option. Thank you.

Comment: that series is designed for bottom entry, so through the board, then into the connector, -PE-BE [catalogue page](http://suddendocs.samtec.com/catalog_english/bcs.pdf). There are other series that do the same thing in surface mount.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't need the connectors to be 100% flush with the board surface, have a look at the [PCB socket range by Harwin](https://www.harwin.com/connector-products/browse-products/?category=Sockets&level=2&code=07A&count=7).

[image: PCB Pins]

There's also a range produced by [Mill-Max](https://www.mill-max.com/new_products/detail/129), but I've not had experience with them. I believe Digikey is their main distributor.

[image: PCB Pins]

Note that theMill-Max sockets are meant to be pressed in, while Harwin sockets are soldered.

Answer (score 4):

These kinds of connectors are dubbed *PCB pin receptacles*.

[image]

The picture shows a multi-position connection.  Single-position receptacles exist too.

Answer (score 3):

Samtec BSW series bottom-entry socket strips might do what you want, although the minimum length shown is 2 pins. They accept .025" square pins.