# PCB mount socket for 1mm diameter pin

Tags: interface, header, socket

I have a module that I want to be able to plug into a custom PCB (i.e. not solder directly). The pins of the module are 1mm diameter and would be inserted perpendicular to the custom PCB. What sort of standard sockets exist for this? I have been unsuccessful searching on Digikey and Mouser. The pins are 0.5 inches apart. The module is the following: http://apowerdesign.com/pdf/h30.pdf

Comment: possibly related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/207230

Comment: None. Use pin receptacles instead.

Comment: I would say that, per the dictionary definition of "socket", the answer is not "none", but rather "those sockets exist and are called pin receptacles".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Mill-Max**](https://www.mill-max.com/) makes a lot of nice pin receptacles for the pin you're citing, [**for instance**](https://www.mill-max.com/products/parameter_search)