# How long can the leads protrude for a typical selective solder machine?

Tags: soldering, pcb-assembly, manufacturing-process

I have an LCD who's leads extend about 10mm past the board surface.

[image]

Can a typical [selective solder machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAOLOSky9P4) fountain reach this high?

If not, any suggestions on the best way to handle long protruding LCD leads like this?

Thanks!

Comment: What's a *selective solder* machine?  Do you mean *wave solder*?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAOLOSky9P4

Comment: Why don't you trim them?

Comment: Just clip them. But I would solder first...

Comment: @olinlathrop imagine a wave soldering machine with a 5mmx5mm wave that is CNC controlled

Comment: Ask your assembly house. Typical things don't matter of they don't do it

Comment: These extended leads are part of the design, so don't want to clip them!

Comment: @PlasmaHH Still in deign phase, so there is no assembly house yet to ask, and also don't want to get stuck with a process that only a limited number of places can do - hence asking about "typical" capabilities! :)

Comment: We used one of these machines at a place I worked at from 2000-2010. The solder fountain does not flow that high, from what I saw of the machine in operation. You would likely need to use another method.

Comment: Do you mean the sort of machine as described by @TonyStewart.EEsince'75? If so put it in your question, comments get deleted.

Comment: "These extended leads are part of the design," - sounds like a bad design. Why does it need such long leads?

Comment: There exists a type of stacking header receptacle where the inserted pins can pass all the way through the board.  Turns out we already have a question on them: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/207230/through-board-connector The "Bottom Entry Socket Strip" listed there as Samtec BSW is the specific style I had in mind, though the discrete contacts like those in machine pin IC sockets look rather interesting too.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Those connectors are surprisingly expensive, but this could be a great alternative if the soldering ends up being impractical. Thanks!

Comment: @BruceAbbott If PCBA DFM was the only requirement driving the design of products, then the world would look like a very different and strange place! :)