# Is there a lower form factor alternative for common female header pins

Tags: connector

I am looking for an alternative for the usual female header pins, one that has a lower profile than the traditional 8.3mm/0.33in high female header pins.

Adafruit has a [low profile](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3008) Female headers but when attached with the tradional male heade pins it still stands tall.

It doesnt have to be a through hole component, I found one that i really like but i am failing to search its name. [image]

It from the raspberry pi POE HAT, a good thing about this (for my case at least) is it can be set on the other side of the board thus lowering the profile even more

but if there are others please do tell

Comment: i have seen a connector that mounted on the underside of the PCB ... the PCB had holes ... the pins would go through the PCB and through the connector

Comment: google `mezanine connector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 'strips' you can get with individual sockets. Types I could find with a quick search looks like this:

[image: Sub-miniature sockets]

…or…

[image: Super Low Profile Sockets]

You can also embed holes into your PCB as described in another [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/207235/91862):

[image: zero profile, solderless press-fit receptacle]

Hard to get any lower than that.

Comment: In the first and second picture those things kinda need a corresponding male connector,  the third one in the other hand looks good

Answer (score 3):

Those in the raspberry pi POE hat are in these ones from [Digi-key](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/harwin-inc/M20-7812045/952-3218-ND/6564954)

Comment: wow ! that's the exact same one ! but the answer provided by pipe has a lower form factor so i went with that one

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to use so-called "bottom entry" connectors. They are SMD but can be contacted either from above or below - you leave holes in the PCB underneath the component. This means that they can be very low profile, down to 2mm or so. Should be available from multiple companies: Samtec, Wurth, Molex etc.

[image]

(This pic is from Wurth, here: https://www.we-online.de/katalog/de/PHD_2_54_SMT_DUAL_SOCKET_HEADER_BOTTOM_ENTRY_6100XX243021/)

Comment: Ohhhh so thats what they are called ! thank you for that sir, makes searching easier in the future

Comment: @Jakequin Just to clarify, I don't know if the ones on your pic are "bottom entry", but you should consider using such, since they are very low profile. And also convenient to use for board-to-board, if you need that.

Comment: yeah those are bottom entry, the raspberry pi has male headers and that hat goes on top of the pi. nonetheless bottom or top those have lower form factor than the traditional female headers